# Magento Coupon code is getting applied but not showing reduced amount in total

Tags: magento

I have created coupon code with 100 Rs. OFF on order above 500 Rs.
It is getting applied successfully, but total is not getting reduced.

and after placing order, mail shows ups reduced amount, so everything is working fine with coupon code, but why it is not showing in checkout page?

i am using onepagecheckout plugin : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/one-page-checkout.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site. Your question isn't programming related. You should ask it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the OSC module and test it?

Comment: thanks, recently i disabled some module to speed up magento, but then i enabled services.. everything worked fine..!